# How to set a converter dynamically for a PrimeFaces component?

Tags: primefaces

I am using `p:autoComplete` inside column of a data table. And I am setting 
converter by using variable assigned to the data table `converter="#{fieldVar.possibleValues}"`

but, it throws : 
**converter="#{fieldVar.possibleValues}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert userConverter of type class java.lang.String to interface javax.faces.convert.Converter**

```
possibleValues is a string
```

If this is not possible then how we can change the converter dynamically.

```
 <p:dataTable var="fieldVar" value="#{dynamicReportBean.screenMetadataDTOs}" id="edit_meta_data_datatable">

                    <p:column headerText="Filter Names">
                        <h:outputText value="#{fieldVar.filedName}"/> 
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Filter Values">
                        <p:inputText value ="#{fieldVar.filedValue}" 
                                     placeholder="#{fieldVar.filedName}"
                                     rendered="#{dynamicReportBean.canRenderFieldType(fieldVar.fieldId, 'TEXTFIELD')}" style="width: 220px">
                        </p:inputText>

                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{fieldVar.filedValue}" 
                                         rendered="#{dynamicReportBean.canRenderFieldType(fieldVar.fieldId, 'DROPDOWN')}" style="width: 220px">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{dynamicReportBean.retrievePossibleDropDownValues(fieldVar.fieldId, fieldVar.fieldType, fieldVar.possibleValues)}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                        <p:selectManyMenu value="#{fieldVar.filedValue}" 
                                          style="width: 220px"
                                          showCheckbox="true"
                                          rendered="#{dynamicReportBean.canRenderFieldType(fieldVar.fieldId, 'SELECT_MANY_CHECKBOX')}">  
                            <f:selectItems value="#{dynamicReportBean.retrievePossibleDropDownValues(fieldVar.fieldId, fieldVar.fieldType, fieldVar.possibleValues)}"/>
                        </p:selectManyMenu>

                        <p:autoComplete  value="#{fieldVar.filedValue}"  
                                         style="width: 220px"
                                         placeholder="autocomplete"
                                         completeMethod="#{dynamicReportBean.getAutoCompleteMethod}"
                                         rendered="#{dynamicReportBean.canRenderFieldType(fieldVar.fieldId, 'AUTOCOMPLETE')}"
                                         scrollHeight="300"
                                         converter="#{fieldVar.possibleValues}" 
                                         size="25">
                            <f:attribute name="converterName" value="#{fieldVar.possibleValues}" />
                            <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{dynamicReportBean.onHandleSelect}"/>
                        </p:autoComplete>

                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
```

if I pass `converter = "userConverter"` It works fine but instead of that I want converter values come dynamically

```
public class UserConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        String value) {
    UserLOVBean lOVBean = null;
    try {
        UserService service = new UserServiceImpl();
        UserFilterDTO filterDTO = new UserFilterDTO();
        UserContext userContext
                = (UserContext) context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().
                get("USER_CONTEXT");
        filterDTO.setCmpCode(userContext.getCmpCode());
        filterDTO.setOrgCode(userContext.getOrgCode());

        if (value != null) {
            filterDTO.setUserId(value);
        }
        for (UserLOVDTO lOVDTO : service.retrieveUserForAutoComplete(
                filterDTO)) {
            if (value.equals(lOVDTO.getUserId())) {
                lOVBean = new UserLOVBean();
                CopyUtil.copyValues(lOVDTO, lOVBean);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Logger.getLogger(UserConverter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                null, ex);
    }
    return lOVBean;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) {
    return String.valueOf(((UserLOVBean) value).getUserId());
}
```

}

Comment: The error looks clear... Your converter is not a converter. Why don't you post the converter code if the error is related to it? And please post everything in [mcve] flavour

Comment: So, it does work when you place the autocomplete outside of the data table?

Comment: Wrong My Converter is working already If I pass it as a string instead of el expression.  Please check it once  @Kukeltje

Comment: I want it  inside data table @JasperdeVries

Comment: How can I know? There is NO converter visible...

Comment: @Kukeltje there is no problem in converter problem is converter attribute of promefaces autocomplete will take javax.faces.convert.Converter as a type how to resolve this problem

Comment: By providing a converter... and not a string in the result of the EL...

Comment: See the documentation: An el expression or a literal text that defines a converter for the component. When it's an EL expression, it's resolved to a converter instance. In case it's a static text, it must refer to a converter id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a converter for `p:autoComplete` (and any other PrimeFaces component) using the `converter` attribute is documented as:

> An EL expression or a literal text that defines a converter for the component. When it's an EL expression, it's resolved to a converter instance. In case it's a static text, it must refer to a converter id.

So, if you want to use an EL expression, it must point to an instance of a converter. In your bean you could simply add:

```
public UserConverter getUserConverter() {
  return new UserConverter();
}
```

And then, in your XHTML, use:

```
<p:anyComponent converter="#{myBean.userConverter}"/>
```